# Difference between code before and after super()

Tags: java, android, oop

Look at the sample codes below

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    ...some code here...
    super.onPause();
}
```

and

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    ...some code here...
}
```

When I asked about differences in code, I did not mean about the flow of execution, which is abvious.

So what is the **real** difference between these codes? When is it advised to use your code **before** `super()` call, and when to use your code **after** `super()` call? I guess there are situations when this does matter.

Comment: @Tim: This is only true in constructors

Comment: Yep, just tested it out. You are correct, I was getting the two mixed up.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You should not place any of your code before `super.onPause()`, cause this method lets the system do what it needs to do to properly pause your application. Any code you want to execute in the `onPause()` callback should be placed after the call to `super.onPause()`. Hope this helps.

Quote from [Activities](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#ImplementingLifecycleCallbacks):

> Note: Your implementation of these lifecycle methods must always call the superclass implementation before doing any work, as shown in the examples above.

Comment: yeah i think you will find that calling the super first follows OO pragma as well, as you would want to do inherited class stuff first before doing unique stuff.

Comment: What about Log? We follow that pattern except for logging, i.e. We always have a Log.d trace just before the super call.

Comment: I prefer LIFO for Android and `onPause` being an outgoing event I call `super.onPause` last

Answer (score 27):

Had to chip in with this link to a thread with an identical subject:

[super.onResume() at beginning or end of method? Does it matter?](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/9ddb2b06c21c8457)

Note the quote from Dianne Hackborn

*Yeah this is a good pattern.  In most cases it probably doesn't matter, but
it's a general rule: during any kind of initialization, let the super class
do their work first; during any kind of finalization, you do your work
first.*

Comment: I think that Dianne's quote can be seen as a rule. After all, she's a member of Android engineers' team, right?!

Comment: That's right. It seems we have conflicting advice from the Android team itself. As it 'probably doesn't matter', I'm going to leave my code as it stands. If it ain't broke I ain't going to fix it.

Answer (score 12):

I've never faced any problems calling the `super` methods before my code and I'm pretty sure I wouldn't have faced any problems if I had called the `super` methods after my code. But usually super classes instances must be initialized before and deinitialized after subclasses. So ideally you should run your code after calling the `super` in `onCreate()`, `onStart()`, `onRestart()` and `onResume()` and before in `onPause()`, `onStop()` and `onDestroy()`.

But one more time. All this code is executed on the UI thread so the order of your code doesn't make great sense excluding some rare cases. But the best idea is to read the source code and to understand how it works and what really happens.

Comment: That's what I've been doing (super last in pause, first in resume etc), taking the view that I want to do things like cancelling timers etc, before the super really does the pause/stop/destroy. However Egor's quote is correct, so that's got me worried now.