# setCacheColorHint on listfragments

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using android compatibility library, and I am having some problems with listfragments using a non solid background. The issue is the same described [on this link](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/listview-backgrounds.html) but calling setCacheColorHint on this.listView() does not have any effects. Does anybody have some idea about what's going on?

```
<fragment class="com.mypackage.MyFragment"
android:id="@+id/my_fragment"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
```

and inside the fragment class, which happens to be a ListFragment, I have

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    getListView().setCacheColorHint(android.R.color.transparent);
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Could you provide some code may please?

Comment: Just added the snippet of the onViewCreated call

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce the problem or circumvent it… In the meantime you should move the super call to be the very first thing executed as discussed on the following post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7191109/difference-between-code-before-and-after-super

Comment: I moved the call but it didn't work..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add `getListView().setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT)` in  `onActivityCreated` method instead `onViewCreated`

Comment: sorry @DroidIn.net, I did not know that I had to accept the answers and I do not come here often. Anyway, I just accepted it. Many thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I found I way to make it work. Simply letting the fragment inflate a custom layout instead of using its own made the trick.

The custom layou just contains the ListView.

I attach the layout and the onCreateView method here, in case it may help somebody else:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list" 
              android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
              android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

And now:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    View res = inflater.inflate(R.layout.generic_list_layout, container, false);
    return res;
}
```

Comment: thanks @Hiral for indenting the code. Sorry if I didn't it myself, I am pretty new here...