# Fragment Activity with a NPE

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-fragments

Hi I'm trying to create my first fragment activities and thnx for the help from Natali [(Cont from this thread)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9110136/742030).  I convertied a class that worked fine into a fragmentand I've made it to this point but now I have the infamous NPE that I cant resolve.

It looks like its from my list-fragment class but I cant figure it out. I'm sure its an easy fix..(?) and I also replaced some variables with hard-code to make it a little easier to run.

Below is a copy of my LogCat and the activities.  Thnx for your help in advance!!

**EDIT:** *The correct log file:*
LogCat:

```
     02-03 10:21:14.410: E/AndroidRuntime(29792): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-03 10:21:14.410: E/AndroidRuntime(29792): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.andaero.test/com.andaero.test.fragments.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-03 10:21:14.410: E/AndroidRuntime(29792):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1815)
02-03 10:21:14.410: E/AndroidRuntime(29792):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1831)
02-03 10:21:14.410: E/AndroidRuntime(29792):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:122)
02-03 10:21:14.410: E/AndroidRuntime(29792):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1024)
02-03 10:21:14.410: E/AndroidRuntime(29792):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-03 10:21:14.410: E/AndroidRuntime(29792):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
02-03 10:21:14.410: E/AndroidRuntime(29792):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
02-03 10:21:14.410: E/AndroidRuntime(29792):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-03 10:21:14.410: E/AndroidRuntime(29792):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
02-03 10:21:14.410: E/AndroidRuntime(29792):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
02-03 10:21:14.410: E/AndroidRuntime(29792):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
02-03 10:21:14.410: E/AndroidRuntime(29792):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-03 10:21:14.410: E/AndroidRuntime(29792): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-03 10:21:14.410: E/AndroidRuntime(29792):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:99)
02-03 10:21:14.410: E/AndroidRuntime(29792):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:94)
02-03 10:21:14.410: E/AndroidRuntime(29792):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:46)
02-03 10:21:14.410: E/AndroidRuntime(29792):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:47)
02-03 10:21:14.410: E/AndroidRuntime(29792):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1539)
02-03 10:21:14.410: E/AndroidRuntime(29792):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1508)
02-03 10:21:14.410: E/AndroidRuntime(29792):    at com.andaero.test.fragments.ListFragment.loadQuery(ListFragment.java:72)
02-03 10:21:14.410: E/AndroidRuntime(29792):    at com.andaero.test.fragments.ListFragment.onActivityCreated(ListFragment.java:60)
02-03 10:21:14.410: E/AndroidRuntime(29792):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:795)
02-03 10:21:14.410: E/AndroidRuntime(29792):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:977)
02-03 10:21:14.410: E/AndroidRuntime(29792):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:960)
02-03 10:21:14.410: E/AndroidRuntime(29792):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1674)
02-03 10:21:14.410: E/AndroidRuntime(29792):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4400)
02-03 10:21:14.410: E/AndroidRuntime(29792):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
02-03 10:21:14.410: E/AndroidRuntime(29792):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1779)
02-03 10:21:14.410: E/AndroidRuntime(29792):    ... 11 more
```

The MainActivity Class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
        }

The ListFragment Class:
public class ListFragment extends android.app.ListFragment {

    boolean mDualPane;
    int mCurCheckPosition = 0;
    protected TextView activityTitle;

    boolean mExternalStorageAvailable = false;
    boolean mExternalStorageWriteable = false;

    String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .toString();
    File dbfile = new File(extStorageDirectory + "/myApp/dB/myApp.db");
    SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(dbfile, null);

    private static final String QUERY_KEY = "SELECT * FROM Regulatory_List";
    private static final String QUERY_ORDER = "ASC";

    private View layout;

    @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview, null);
            return layout;

        }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        Bundle extras = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();

        String q = null;
        if (extras != null) {
            q = extras.getString(QUERY_KEY);
        }
        loadQuery(q);

    }

    public void loadQuery(String q) {

        if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
                Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {

            String qO = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("QUERY_ORDER");

            Cursor c = db.rawQuery(q + " ORDER BY `_id` " + qO, null);
            setListAdapter(new QueryAdapter(getActivity(), c));
            db.close();

        } else {
            Alerts.sdCardMissing(getActivity());
        }
    }

    public class QueryAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

        public QueryAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
            super(context, c);
            LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }

        @Override
        public void bindView(View v, Context context, final Cursor c) {

            int tvLabel = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("label");
            String label = c.getString(tvLabel);
            final TextView labelTxt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.label);

            if (labelTxt != null) {
                labelTxt.setText("(" + label + ")");
            }

            int tvTitle = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("title");
            final String title = c.getString(tvTitle);
            TextView titleTxt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.listTitle);

            if (titleTxt != null) {
                titleTxt.setText(title);
            }

            int tvDescription = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("description");
            String description = c.getString(tvDescription);
            TextView descriptionTxt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.caption);

            if (descriptionTxt != null) {
                descriptionTxt.setText(description);
            }

            int tvDate = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("date");
            String date = c.getString(tvDate);
            TextView dateTxt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.dateAdded);

            if (dateTxt != null) {
                dateTxt.setText(date);
            }

            int tvGoto = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("gotoURL");
            final String gotoURL = c.getString(tvGoto);
            TextView gotoTxt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.dummy);

            if (gotoTxt != null) {
                gotoTxt.setText(gotoURL);
            }

            gotoTxt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            v.setTag(gotoURL);

            final ListView lv = getListView();
            lv.setEnabled(true);
            lv.setClickable(true);

            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int arg2,
                        long arg3) {

                    String url = "";
                    url = (String) v.getTag();

                    int nI = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("intent");
                    String intent = c.getString(nI);
                    Class<?> myIntent = null;
                    try {
                        myIntent = Class.forName("com.andaero.test.fragments"
                                + intent);
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    int tvTitle = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("title");
                    String title = c.getString(tvTitle);

                    int tvLabel = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("label");
                    String label = c.getString(tvLabel);

                    String queryKey = "SELECT * FROM " + label;
                    c.close();
                    db.close();

                    Intent i = new Intent();
                    i.putExtra("QUERY_KEY", queryKey);
                    i.putExtra("KEY_URL", url);
                    i.putExtra("KEY_SUBTITLE", title);
                    i.putExtra("KEY_LABEL", label);
                    i.putExtra("KEY_INTENT", intent);
                    i.putExtra("QUERY_ORDER", "ASC");
                    i.putExtra("KEY_YPOS", "0.0");
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
            final View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                    R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            return v;
        }
    }

    }
```

Comment: Why are you doing this "q = extras.getString(QUERY_KEY);"  Is the query being pass from another activity?  Seem like you want loadQuery(QUERY_KEY);

Comment: @Frohnzie Yes, its being passed by another activity. The original class worked fine.  I just hard-coded it for now after getrting the NPE to make it easier to debug.

Comment: @Frohnzie Thnx! I looked at it again (closer) and I had put my string in the wrong place. Replace: `String q = null;` with: `String q = "SELECT * FROM Regulatory_List";` That got it working.

Comment: That means you are not passing your extras properly.  "extras" must be null.  Post code around startActivity().

Comment: @Frohnzie  My code works fine the way I have it - I just put the hard-code for testing in the wrong place. If you want credit for helping me out, add your first comment as an Answer below.  Thnx again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
```

Means you don't have a column named _id in you table.

See this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html).

"Adapter that exposes data from a Cursor to a ListView widget. The Cursor must include a column named "_id" or this class will not work."

EDIT:

Looks like the query may be invalid.  I think what you want is:

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(QUERY_KEY + " ORDER BY `_id` " + QUERY_ORDER, null);
```

If you still have issues add more info to log:

```
Log.e("QUERY", q + " ORDER BY `_id` " + qO);
```

EDIT:

Why are you doing this `q = extras.getString(QUERY_KEY);` Is the query being pass from another activity? Seem like you want `loadQuery(QUERY_KEY);`

Comment: Thnx, I copied the wrong log file.  The corrected Log is above.

Comment: I dont think _id need quotes either.