# Fragment did not create a view

Tags: android

MyFragment.java

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    private onItemSelectedListener listener;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container,
                false);
        btn_myButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_new_client);
        btn_myButton .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                updateDetail("New Layout");
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    Button btn_myButton;

    public interface onItemSelectedListener {
        public void onItemSelected(String link);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        if (activity instanceof onItemSelectedListener) {
            listener = (onItemSelectedListener) activity;
        } else {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implemenet OnItemSelectedListener");
        }
    }
    public void updateDetail(String s) {
        listener.onItemSelected(s);
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
    onItemSelectedListener {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

public void onItemSelected(String link) {
    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    Fragment fragment;
    if ("New Layout".equals(link)) {
        fragment = new Fragment1();
        transaction.replace(R.id.detailFragment, fragment);
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
}
```

Fragment1.java

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.newfragmentt, container,
                false);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_new_client"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="8"
        android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="@string/new_client"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" >
    </Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

main_activity.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#4B6C9E"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <fragment        
        android:id="@+id/FragmentId"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        class="com.examples.MyProject.MyFragment" >
    </fragment>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/detailFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2" >
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

LogCat error:

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.elintsys.iCaseDiary/com.examples.MyProject.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251)
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1862)
    at com.examples.MyProject.MainActivity.onCreate(CaseEntryActivity.java:15)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4492)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
    ... 11 more
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment com.elintsys.iCaseDiary.CaseEntryFragment did not create a view.
    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4293)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:673)
    ... 21 more
 Sending signal. PID: 16275 SIG: 9
```

Please help me friends.

Comment: you need to reverse this `setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)`. call super and then setContentView

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to reverse this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main_activity); 
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState).
```

into this:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState). 
setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
```

in your activity's `onCreate`.

Comment: Any ideas why is this? I always leave super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) as the last statement in my Activities' onCreate.

Comment: @Mark https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-developers/wGt4qiwLy3Y/BwRGmRgDX08J and here's one more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7191109/difference-between-code-before-and-after-super. Do look @ dianne hackborn's comment

Answer (score 3):

I was also getting this error, even though I was calling setContentView after super.onCreate.  In my case I was setting up a worker fragment in my super class' onCreate method, which was being called before setContentView and triggering the bug documented here:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22564

I had to move initialization of the worker fragment into a separate method called later in the activity lifecycle to work around this.

By request, here is what that code looks like:

```
public class BaseActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private static final String TAG_TASK_FRAGMENT = "task_fragment";

    protected TaskFragment taskFragment; // Used to hold a reference to the active activity between config changes

    protected void setupTaskFragment() {
        // It would be great if we could just do this in onCreate, but setting up the task fragment
        // before calling setContentView() triggers the bug described here:
        //
        // https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22564
        //
        // So we just need to make sure Activities that run async tasks call this setup function
        // before they do.

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        taskFragment = (TaskFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(TAG_TASK_FRAGMENT);

        // If the Fragment is non-null, then it is currently being
        // retained across a configuration change.
        if (taskFragment == null) {
            taskFragment = new TaskFragment();
            fm.beginTransaction().add(taskFragment, TAG_TASK_FRAGMENT).commit();
            fm.executePendingTransactions();
        }

    }

}

public class ChildActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  // If this call adds a fragment, you will have problems
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_child);
        setupTaskFragment(); // So we have to add our task fragment here, after we've called setContentView()

        // further initialization here
    }

}

/**
 *
 *  TaskFragment
 *
 * We use this fragment to manage async tasks between configuration changes.  The fragment calls
 * setRetainInstance(true) in its constructor, which makes it so that it will not be recreated
 * between configuration events (like screen rotation).  Async tasks running from the fragment 
 * can then be kept up to date on which activity they belong to.
 */

public class TaskFragment extends Fragment {

    private ArrayList<AsyncTask> asyncTasks = new ArrayList<AsyncTask>();

    public TaskFragment() {
        super();
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    public void addTask(AsyncTask task) {
        asyncTasks.add(task);
    }

    public void removeTask(AsyncTask task) {
        asyncTasks.remove(task);
    }

    public Application getApplication() {
        Activity activity = getActivity();
        if (activity != null)
            return activity.getApplication();
        else
            return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        for (AsyncTask task : asyncTasks) {
            task.onAttach(activity);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        for (AsyncTask task : asyncTasks) {
            task.onDetach();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've added a code sample that shows what I had to do.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Mel Stanley said you also need to ensure that you add the android:tag to your xml activity where the fragment is loaded:

```
<fragment
android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:name="com.your_app.name.fragments.NameOfFragment"
android:tag="fragment_tag"
tools:layout="@layout/layout_fragment" 
/>
```

This ensures that when the fragment is being loaded for the first time using the xml it is not reloaded using Mel's code. If you left this out you would have 2 loads of the fragment on first run - this is a problem if you have asynchronous requests that change the layout upon completion.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, yet already had `setContentView` and `super.onCreate`. Adding the following inside of my fragment activity fixed the issue:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}
```

After moving further into my project, this issue persisted, 2nd fix was replacing:

```
    <fragment
    android:id="@+id/output"
    class=".Fragment_1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

With:

```
    <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_frame_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name=".Fragment_1"
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_two" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

Apparently, "You cannot replace a fragment that is statically placed in an xml layout file" as found in the answer to this question: [Android - fragment .replace() doesn't replace content - puts it on top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810348/android-fragment-replace-doesnt-replace-content-puts-it-on-top)