# Android: Unable to inflate activity_main due to fragment added in it

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am getting these three errors while it starts the app and it crashes immediately after that(I've added all the references where required):

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29: Error inflating class fragment
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29: Error inflating class fragment
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment com.tifinnearme.priteshpatel.materialdrawer.NavigationFragment did not create a view.
```

Here is Mainactivity.java

```
package com.tifinnearme.priteshpatel.materialdrawer;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
Toolbar toolbar;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    //Create object for drawer layout

    NavigationFragment navFrag=     (NavigationFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.drawer_fragment);
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout=(DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);//Get the object of drawer layout

    navFrag.setUp(R.id.drawer_fragment,drawerLayout,toolbar);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    if(id==R.id.navigate)
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(this,Subactivity.class));
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

NavigationFragment.java

```
package com.tifinnearme.priteshpatel.materialdrawer;


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;


/**
* A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
*/
public class NavigationFragment extends Fragment {

public static final String PREF_FILE_NAME="testprefs";
public static final String KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER="User learned drawer";
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;//indicate whether user has opened drawer first time or not(
private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;
private View containerView;
public NavigationFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mUserLearnedDrawer=Boolean.valueOf(readFromPrefs(getActivity(), KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, "false"));//false indicates user doesn't know about drawer
    if(savedInstanceState!=null){
        mFromSavedInstanceState=true;
    }
}


public void setUp(int drawer_fragment, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, Toolbar toolbar) {
    //Initialize the drawer layout and toggle
    containerView=getActivity().findViewById(drawer_fragment);
    mDrawerLayout=drawerLayout;
    mDrawerToggle=new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(),mDrawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.drawer_open,R.string.drawer_close){
        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            if(!mUserLearnedDrawer)
            {
                mUserLearnedDrawer=true;
                savedPreferences(getActivity(),KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER,mUserLearnedDrawer+"");
                //Save this value into our Key to indicate that user has seen drawer
            }
            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();//It creates Actionbar again when drawer toggles


        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
    if(!mUserLearnedDrawer && !mFromSavedInstanceState)
    {
        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(containerView);
    }
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
}
public static void savedPreferences(Context context,String prefName,String prefValue){
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs=context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPrefs.edit();
    editor.putString(prefName,prefValue);
    /*editor.commit();*///It wait for the operation to become successful
    editor.apply();//It doesn't wait for the operation to become successful
}
public static String readFromPrefs(Context context,String prefName,String prefDefaultValue){
    SharedPreferences getPrefs=context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return  getPrefs.getString(prefName,prefDefaultValue);
}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar"></include>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
</RelativeLayout>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/drawer_fragment"
    android:name="com.tifinnearme.priteshpatel.materialdrawer.NavigationFragment"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation" />


 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**EDIT:** Duplicate question doesn't resolved my problem. I'm still having the same problem.If anyone could help with this, than it'd be great. thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fragment did not create a view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18307533/fragment-did-not-create-a-view)

Comment: thanks @2Dee for quick reply but that(other question) doesn't resolved my problem.

Comment: Well, your fragment *is* initially empty and does not create a view when it's supposed to (namely in `onCreateView()` called by `onCreate()`). Try moving the `setUp()` code to where the lifecycle wants it.

Comment: Thanks @dhke for the reply but could elaborate a little bit more? Actually, i am a  beginner to this. So, that'd be your great help!

Comment: @pritesh Can you augment your question with information on what the fragment is supposed to do? Because currently you are passing in `View s (i.e. drawerlayout) from the outside to your fragment and I'm not so sure, why.

Comment: Never mind @dhke..I just figured out that public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,                 Bundle savedInstanceState) was commented by mistake..but anyway, thanks for your time ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your:

```
<fragment
android:id="@+id/drawer_fragment"
android:name="com.tifinnearme.priteshpatel.materialdrawer.NavigationFragment"
android:layout_width="240dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="start"
app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation"
tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation" />
```

to be:

```
<FrameLayout
       android:id="@+id/content_frame"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

then add your fragment to `content_frame`:

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction
            .replace(R.id.content_frame, new your_fragment)
            .commit();
```

Comment: thanks @Xcihnegn for reply but could you explain without having 'Framelayout' (i.e, with fragment in activity_main.xml)?

Comment: For your original codes problem is that you missed `onCreateView(...)` to create view in your `NavigationFragment`

Comment: Yup @ Xcihnegn..I just found that i've commented that method by mistake..but anyway, thanks for identifying..:-)

Comment: @pritesh check my answer to the [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29545479/illegalstateexception-did-not-create-a-view-when-screen-orientation-changes/29556331#29556331) if you use with fragment in your `activity_main`

Comment: yes, indeed that helped me a lot. thanks for your response and sorry for the delayed replay.

Comment: So please accept the answer if solve your issue, or upvote the answer if just help you