# Horizontal Scroll View with images and iamges should be clicked?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

[i want something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQn2i.png)

HorizontalScrollView with images and images should me marked or unmarked by the user. 
As you can see in the attached image,User can select two images at a time.
Please see the attached image.

Comment: include your Navigation class

Comment: they only allow me 2 images to put

Comment: edit your question and paste the code - not as image

Comment: Check this question again.Thanks for your help

Comment: there is no code in the question now. If i remember right, based on the stack trace pic you linked earlier, the error was with Navigation class (fragment) did not create any view.

Comment: how can i create view

Comment: hmm.... have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18307533/fragment-did-not-create-a-view

Comment: Thanks for your help the issue is resolved the reason for this is that my fragment not creating any view.

Comment: HorizontalScrollView with images and images should me marked or unmarked by the use. As you can see the in the attached images,user can select two images at a time. Please see the attached image.

Answer (score 0):

Check your dependencies in the build.gradle file. Different versions of support library may be cause.

For example

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.0.+'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.0.+'
```

If any library uses another version like

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
```

This may be cause of error.