# Strange launch behaviour causing a crash

Tags: android

I have seen many reports from the field from one of my apps (~1% of users see it per day) of an error with not being able to unpack a fragment resource, with the ultimate reason being "Fragment ...MyRootFragment did not create a view". The fragment class in question has nothing but an `onCreate` method which inflates a simple `LinearLayout`.

Today I finally experienced the problem for myself, with a different product, and grabbed some logcat output, which is below.

It appears (at `09:46:13.776`) that the problem is caused by Android trying to use the apk file from a different app in order to supply the resources for this app. Although I've named it `unrelatedapp` in the logcat, it is in fact derived from the same codebase (`baseapp`).

I haven't launched `unrelatedapp` in a couple of days. I installed `myapp` yesterday and ran it a couple of times, then left the device overnight. The crash happened the first time I tried to launch it this morning, and then I had several successful launches following that.

I unzipped `myapp`'s APK, grepped for `unrelatedapp` and got no hits, so I'm fairly confident that it's not a built-in problem. In the original app in which I was seeing field reports of this problem, it's fairly unlikely that users would have 2 of my apps installed.

Has anyone seen this kind of problem before? Any idea how it might be resolved?

```
2020-01-31 09:46:13.581 769-28885/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.baseapp.activity.MainActivity (has extras)} from uid 10031
2020-01-31 09:46:13.583 567-8233/? D/audio_route: Apply path: speaker-protected
2020-01-31 09:46:13.586 567-8233/? D/audio_hw_primary: enable_snd_device: snd_device(95: vi-feedback)
2020-01-31 09:46:13.587 567-8233/? D/audio_route: Apply path: vi-feedback
2020-01-31 09:46:13.587 567-8233/? D/audio_hw_primary: enable_audio_route: usecase(24) apply and update mixer path: spkr-vi-record
2020-01-31 09:46:13.587 567-8233/? D/audio_route: Apply path: spkr-vi-record
2020-01-31 09:46:13.612 567-8233/? D/audio_hw_primary: enable_audio_route: usecase(1) apply and update mixer path: low-latency-playback
2020-01-31 09:46:13.612 567-8233/? D/audio_route: Apply path: low-latency-playback
2020-01-31 09:46:13.628 769-783/? W/BroadcastQueue: Permission Denial: receiving Intent { act=com.android.launcher3.action.LAUNCH flg=0x10 pkg=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox (has extras) } to com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.apps.gsa.reflection.ReflectionReceiver requires com.android.launcher3.permission.RECEIVE_LAUNCH_BROADCASTS due to sender com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox (uid 10031)
2020-01-31 09:46:13.634 769-783/? W/BroadcastQueue: Permission Denial: receiving Intent { act=com.android.launcher3.action.LAUNCH flg=0x10 pkg=com.google.android.gms (has extras) } to ProcessRecord{baebeb4 14853:com.google.android.gms.persistent/u0a13} (pid=14853, uid=10013) requires com.android.launcher3.permission.RECEIVE_LAUNCH_BROADCASTS due to sender com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox (uid 10031)
2020-01-31 09:46:13.634 769-783/? W/BroadcastQueue: Permission Denial: receiving Intent { act=com.android.launcher3.action.LAUNCH flg=0x10 pkg=com.google.android.gms (has extras) } to com.google.android.gms/.chimera.GmsIntentOperationService$GmsExternalReceiver requires com.android.launcher3.permission.RECEIVE_LAUNCH_BROADCASTS due to sender com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox (uid 10031)
2020-01-31 09:46:13.651 567-8233/? E/msm8974_platform: ramp_speaker_gain: Could not get ctl for mixer cmd - Left Speaker Gain or Right Speaker Gain, not applying speaker gain ramp
2020-01-31 09:46:13.651 567-8233/? D/audio_hw_primary: out_write: retry previous failed cal level set
2020-01-31 09:46:13.651 567-8233/? W/msm8974_platform: platform_send_gain_dep_cal: Usecase list is empty
2020-01-31 09:46:13.659 769-1268/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc 7608:com.mycompany.myapp/u0a1008 for activity com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.baseapp.activity.MainActivity
2020-01-31 09:46:13.742 15263-7566/? I/PBSessionCacheImpl: Deleted sessionId[67128963592940959] from persistence.
2020-01-31 09:46:13.752 15263-15575/? W/SearchServiceCore: Abort, client detached.
2020-01-31 09:46:13.776 1279-1705/? W/asset: Asset path /data/app/com.mycompany.unrelatedapp-7FjAm9N4JRcpJvnxYymccg==/base.apk is neither a directory nor file (type=1).
2020-01-31 09:46:13.777 1279-1705/? E/ResourcesManager: failed to add asset path /data/app/com.mycompany.unrelatedapp-7FjAm9N4JRcpJvnxYymccg==/base.apk
2020-01-31 09:46:13.777 1279-1705/? W/PackageManager: Failure retrieving resources for com.mycompany.unrelatedapp
2020-01-31 09:46:13.778 1279-1705/? W/asset: Asset path /data/app/com.mycompany.unrelatedapp-7FjAm9N4JRcpJvnxYymccg==/base.apk is neither a directory nor file (type=1).
2020-01-31 09:46:13.778 1279-1705/? E/ResourcesManager: failed to add asset path /data/app/com.mycompany.unrelatedapp-7FjAm9N4JRcpJvnxYymccg==/base.apk
2020-01-31 09:46:13.778 1279-1705/? W/PackageManager: Failure retrieving resources for com.mycompany.unrelatedapp
2020-01-31 09:46:13.866 7608-7608/? I/MultiDex: VM with version 2.1.0 has multidex support
2020-01-31 09:46:13.866 7608-7608/? I/MultiDex: Installing application
2020-01-31 09:46:13.866 7608-7608/? I/MultiDex: VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
2020-01-31 09:46:13.938 7608-7608/? D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth is not linked. Skipping initialization.
2020-01-31 09:46:13.939 7608-7608/? D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping initialization.
2020-01-31 09:46:13.940 7608-7608/? I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
2020-01-31 09:46:13.954 7608-7608/? I/FacebookInitProvider: Failed to auto initialize the Facebook SDK
    A valid Facebook app id must be set in the AndroidManifest.xml or set by calling FacebookSdk.setApplicationId before initializing the sdk.
        at com.facebook.FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(FacebookSdk.java:276)
        at com.facebook.FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(FacebookSdk.java:232)
        at com.facebook.internal.FacebookInitProvider.onCreate(FacebookInitProvider.java:20)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1919)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1894)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6239)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5805)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5722)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1656)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
2020-01-31 09:46:13.965 7608-7608/? I/com.mycompany.myapp: Application [com.mycompany.myapp] starting
2020-01-31 09:46:13.970 7608-7608/? I/com.mycompany.myapp: Application commit id: 9ed3096
2020-01-31 09:46:13.970 7608-7608/? I/com.mycompany.myapp: Application build date: 2020-01-30 15:34:00 -0700
2020-01-31 09:46:13.970 7608-7608/? I/com.mycompany.myapp: Application build configuration: release
2020-01-31 09:46:13.971 7608-7608/? I/com.mycompany.myapp: Application version: 1.0-4 / 9ed3096 [R]
2020-01-31 09:46:13.971 7608-7608/? I/com.mycompany.myapp: System name: Android
2020-01-31 09:46:13.971 7608-7608/? I/com.mycompany.myapp: System version: 8.1.0
2020-01-31 09:46:13.972 7608-7608/? I/com.mycompany.myapp: Device model: Nexus 5X
2020-01-31 09:46:13.973 7608-7608/? I/com.mycompany.myapp: Device interface idiom: 0
2020-01-31 09:46:13.974 7608-7608/? I/com.mycompany.myapp: Device vendor identifier: B26A1A6A-75B3-19F8-B26A-1A6A58DC1AA4
2020-01-31 09:46:13.977 7608-7608/? I/com.mycompany.myapp: Device id is: B26A1A6A-75B3-19F8-B26A-1A6A58DC1AA4
2020-01-31 09:46:14.049 7608-7627/? I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 15300
2020-01-31 09:46:14.049 7608-7627/? I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
2020-01-31 09:46:14.049 7608-7627/? I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
      adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.mycompany.myapp
2020-01-31 09:46:14.058 7608-7608/? V/File read doc: /data/user/0/com.mycompany.myapp/cache/com.mycompany.myapp/saved/readdocuments.json
2020-01-31 09:46:14.073 3647-3791/? I/Icing: IndexChimeraService.getServiceInterface callingPackage=com.android.chrome componentName=null serviceId=36
2020-01-31 09:46:14.087 3647-3791/? I/Icing: IndexChimeraService.getServiceInterface callingPackage=com.google.android.gms componentName=null serviceId=36
2020-01-31 09:46:14.100 7608-7632/? D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline
2020-01-31 09:46:14.132 3647-3791/? I/Icing: IndexChimeraService.getServiceInterface callingPackage=com.google.android.gms componentName=null serviceId=30
2020-01-31 09:46:14.137 567-722/? D/audio_hw_primary: disable_audio_route: usecase(1) reset and update mixer path: low-latency-playback
2020-01-31 09:46:14.143 7608-7608/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM


    --------- beginning of crash
2020-01-31 09:46:14.148 7608-7608/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.mycompany.myapp, PID: 7608
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.baseapp.activity.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment com.mycompany.mylibrary.ui.MyRootFragment did not create a view.
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:3706)
```

MainActivity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment android:id="@+id/rootFragment"
          android:name="com.mycompany.mylibrary.ui.MyRootFragment"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

MyRootFragment code:

```
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_root_fragment, container, false);
    return view;
  }
```

my_root_fragment layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: so have you checked this line: A valid Facebook app id must be set in the AndroidManifest.xml or set by calling FacebookSdk.setApplicationId before initializing the sdk.

Comment: You know, I hadn't, even though it's staring me right in the face there. Seems a little unlikely that it would be the cause, given that it's logged after the resource / package stuff, but I will add that in to the live app and see if it helps.

Comment: Think that's a red herring on further evaluation — it's a numeric id rather than an android package id, so I can't see how it would have any effect on resource paths.

Comment: paste the layout code of activity and fragment.

Comment: I have edited the post with the layouts.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18307533/fragment-did-not-create-a-view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the bright idea to run the app again while looking at logcat, and the reference to `unrelatedapp` was still there on successful launches (also deleted `unrelatedapp` and the message went away). Therefore I think it's a red herring, and this question is probably no different from the other instances of "Fragment did not create a view."